# Pattern to update a UItableView and its datasource after filtering with NSPredicate

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uikit

This seems like it should be straight forward.  Technically I can make this work, but if I want to perform certain UI animations, (using deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:) things get hairy. It seems as though the datasource and UI are fighting over who should delete first. Then I have to artificially keep data around for the UI update.

My current setup:

In my model:

1. Create a multidimensional NSArray to
   hold my data. (each sub array
   represents a section).
2. Place a NSDictionary in each section
   array to represent the data for an
   individual cell.

In my View Controller:

1. Create a multidimensional NSArray to
   hold my Cell Controllers (mimicking
   the data structure).
2. Assign each model dictionary to an
   ivar in the appropriate Cell
   Controller.
3. Hook up the data to the cell

This gets my UITableView on screen with cells properly displayed. Now if I want to filter the data in the table I do the following:

In my model:

1. Create an instance of NSPredicate.
2. Filter each subarray of the
   multidimensional array.
3. Set a flag in each dictionary that
   is within the results of the
   filtered array.

In my View controller:

1. I create a new Multidimensional
   NSArray. This array will hold the
   cell controllers of the "filtered
   data"
2. Loop through the current
   Multidimensional Controller array.
   Add it to the new "filtered array if
   it's model's flag is set.
3. Replace the unfiltered Controller
   array with the new one.
4. Update the table.

This also works very well. As long as I don't mind the UI updating instantaneously. If I want to delete rows with animation, I must pass those indexes to the table to be deleted.

To accomplish this, I add a few more steps to the view controller:

In my View controller:

1. I create a new Multidimensional
   NSArray. This array will hold the
   cell controllers of the "filtered
   data"
2. Loop through the current
   Multidimensional Controller array.
   Add it to the new "filtered array if
   it's model's flag is set.
3. Create a new NSArray to hold indexes
   to be deleted.
4. Loop through the current
   Multidimensional Controller array.
   Add its cell's index to the
   "toBeDeleted" array if its model's
   flag is NOT set.
5. Replace the unfiltered Controller
   array with the new one.
6. perform
   deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimationn.

So far this method doesn't work the greatest. I am having issues deleting the rows with edge cases (empty sections and all visible cells being deleted).

This made me think maybe my methodology is flawed. Has anyone implemented this in an app? How did you solve this? Do your row animations work?

Comment: I have implemented this using the design which I outlined [here](http://www.theflyingjalapenolives.com/2009/06/filtering-uitableviews-deleting-multiple-uitableviewcells-with-animation/) (personal blog post) I will post some specific code when I clean it up and make it a bit more generic.

Answer (score 0):

Not to make matters worse, but have you tried NSPredicate on an actual device?

I found that NSPredicate worked on the Simulator, but much like NSXMLDocument, wasn't available on the device itself (2.2.1).

---

update: Given that NSPredicate is available, all I can add is that I've had unpredictable results with deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation as well - I had to settle for calling reloadData and having a non-animated transition.

Fortunately, since I have a highly "subtractive" filter in my app, there's typically a lot of movement, so it's obvious to the user that something has happened.

In your case where visible changes are potentially non-obvious, I suspect that from a usability perspective, it might be sufficient simply to use an animated UIImageView moving from north to south across the UITableView area. (a challenge in it's own right, unfortunately).

This would have the added bonus of confirming the filter's application to the user even if no visible changes occurred.

Comment: This isn't available on 2.2.1, you are right. But is available on [redacted].